# Matlab-Part of the image is missing when drawing the segmented function

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, piecewise

```
x = -10:0.01:10;
y = sin(x.^2).*(x<-1)+log(x+4).*(x>=-1);
plot(x,y);
grid on;
axis([-10,10,-6,6]);
```

Resulting plot, zoomed on the break:
[image]

The sin plot is complete when drawn separately, and the plot is complete when other functions are superimposed. However, when log (x+a) is superimposed, the plot will be broken at x=-a.

This is the function of my target plot. Is my implementation method incorrect? Please correct.

Original function:

[image]

I just contacted MATLAB and didn't know the solution. I hope it can be solved effectively. Thank you. English comes from machine translation, please forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

Your selection method, multiplying by a Boolean, does not play nicely with `log(0)`, which is `-Inf`. Multiplying infinity and zero gives `NaN` (not a number), which pollutes the rest of the equation and cannot be plotted. Instead, one way is to perform your selection before applying your functions and concatenate the results:

```
x = -10:0.01:10;
y = [sin(x(x<-1).^2), log(x(x>=-1)+4)];
plot(x,y);
grid on;
axis([-10,10,-6,6]);
```